# Upload text files to MS SQL server automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I frequently receive text and excel files which I have to upload in local MS SQL Server. Is there any tool or command available that can automate this task. For Bulk upload provided by MS SQL you have to create the blank table first, I dont want to create a new table manually each time. Please help

Comment: Sounds like you're after SSIS?

Comment: If not SSIS, Powershell could do this in some lines of code as well, using `SqlBulkCopy` and then run it with a Windows task.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on SSIS

Comment: Are all the files so different that they need a special table each?

Comment: Yes they have completely different field names and data types.

Answer (score 3):

Don't need  to create a data table  manually  . In MS Sql  server  there  is a function  for  that  .

1. Right  click on  Database Name
2. Then go  to  'Tasks' and  then go to the  tab  'Import Data' & click on  that
3. you will  get  the  data  export  , import  wizard, Click  next.
4. If  excel file  , Select  data source as  'Microsoft Excel' then browse  the  excel file  (make  sure  your  excel  file  save  in 97-2003 format). 
   if  text  file  , Select  data source as 'Flat File Source' , then browse  the  file .
5. Proceed  with the  wizard ,  you will  get  the  data  table with relevant data.

Comment: Yes I know this feature & I currently use that only but to do it manually for say 10 files is cumbersome. I want that all the files if they are 10 or 20 inside a specific folder should get uploaded at once in sql server.

Comment: @AnujAgarwal check out this link: [How to loop through files in a specified folder, load one by one and move to archive folder using SSIS](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm)